# Query for arrival time, departure time, and total distance between source, destination, and connecting trains

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table train_schedule

```
|   id   |   train_no   |train_name | station_no|station_code|arr_time| dep_time  | distance|src_station_code|dest_station_code|

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1   |   0123       | ABC       | 1         |     ROU    |00:00:00| 06:00:00  |     0   | ROU            |     BBS   |
|    2   |   0123       | ABC       | 2         |     CLM    |06:50:00| 06:55:00  |     100 | ROU            |     BBS   |
|    3   |   0123       | ABC       | 3         |     GNT    |07:30:00| 07:32:00  |     150 | ROU            |     BBS   |
|    4   |   0123       | ABC       | 4         |     BBS    |08:30:00| 00:00:00  |     300 | ROU            |     BBS   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    5   |   0224       | XYZ       | 1         |     HTE    |00:00:00| 09:00:00  |     0   | HTE            |     BBS   |
|    6   |   0224       | XYZ       | 2         |     ROU    |09:51:00| 09:56:00  |     200 | HTE            |     BBS   |
|    7   |   0224       | XYZ       | 3         |     BBS    |10:30:00| 00:00:00  |     550 | HTE            |     BBS   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    8   |   0774       | PQR       | 1         |     NDLS   |00:00:00| 02:00:00  |     0   | NDLS           |     BNC   |
|    9   |   0774       | PQR       | 2         |     ROU    |04:50:00| 04:56:00  |     200 | NDLS           |     BNC  |
|    10  |   0774       | PQR       | 3         |     BBS    |06:30:00| 06:45:00  |     450 | NDLS           |     BNC  |
|    11  |   0774       | PQR       | 4         |     BNC    |10:30:00| 00:00:00  |     550 | NDLS           |     BNC  |
```

User will give input as a source and destination for ex: **ROU** and **BBS**

Output will be 3 train for this selection, with **train_no,arr_time,dep_time,and total distance**, i tried with different possibilities able to get trains between sorce and destination but not connecting trains.

Desired result:

```
|   id   |   train_no   |train_name | station_code|dep_time| arr_time  | distance  |        FROM     |     TO    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1   |   0123       | ABC       |      ROU    |06:00:00| 08:30:00  |    300    |        ROU      |     BBS   |
|    2   |   0224       | XYZ       |      ROU    |09:56:00| 10:30:00  |550-200=350|        ROU      |     BBS   |
|    3   |   0774       | PQR       |      ROU    |04:56:00| 06:30:00  |450-200=250|        ROU      |     BBS   |
```

I have tried with following query though it gives the desired result but only with the train between src_station_code and destination_station_code I want connecting trains also.

```
select FirstSet.train_no, FirstSet.total_distance, FirstSet.arrival_time, FirstSet.source_station_code, FirstSet.source_station_name, FirstSet.destination_station_code, FirstSet.destination_station_name, SecondSet.departure_time
 from 
 ( SELECT train_no, MAX(distance) AS total_distance, arrival_time,train_name,source_station_code,destination_station_code,source_station_name,destination_station_name FROM train_schedule as q where distance = (select max(distance) from train_schedule where train_no = q.train_no)and (src_stn_code='ROU' and dst_stn_code='BBS') GROUP BY train_no )
 as FirstSet left join 

( SELECT train_no,source_station_code,departure_time FROM train_schedule where station_no='1' and (src_stn_code='ROU' and dst_stn_code='BBS') ) as SecondSet on FirstSet.train_no = SecondSet.train_no order by FirstSet.train_no
```

Comment: SOURCE and DESTINATION cannot be valid values for arr_time/dep_time. You could use NULL for these.

Comment: you are right ..edited the question

Comment: Just a comment on table structure, it looks like train_name, src_station_code, and dest_station_code are redundant and should be removed from your table. What you presented looks more like a view of several tables.

Comment: I agree, but i want to keep only one table for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put your data and the solution in this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c402ef/1).

Here is the solution SQL to your question (but missing the new id for the result):

```
SELECT ts1.train_no,ts1.train_name,ts1.station_code,ts1.dep_time,ts2.arr_time,
  ts2.distance -ts1.distance As distance, 
  ts1.station_code AS 'FROM', ts2.station_code AS 'TO'
  FROM train_schedule ts1 JOIN train_schedule ts2 
  ON ts1.train_no = ts2.train_no AND ts1.station_no < ts2.station_no
  WHERE ts1.station_code = 'ROU' AND ts2.station_code = 'BBS';
```

Comment: Works Perfect!! Thanks sir you saved my day...This is the best solution..